# Aqueous glucose solution concentration computation

Tags: physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution, stoichiometry

The question in my worksheet is as follows:

> You dissolve $\pu{1.451 mol}$ of glucose in water to a volume of $\pu{250 mL}$. The mass of the glucose is $\pu{261 g}$ and the molecular weight $\pu{180.16 g/mol}$. What is the glucose concentration of your solution expressed as $\pu{mol/L}$?

I felt like this was a straightforward $\pu{5.80 M}$. But now I feel like that's too easy, since they tell us the amount of moles dissolved. Why give that information when the mass and molecular weight is also provided? I'm just wondering if I'm right here or if it really is trickier.

Comment: Yep, looks like they gave extraneous information, and your answer is *almost* correct -- but they give the concentration to three decimal places, and remember the expected *units*.

Comment: There is no law of nature saying that all provided info is essential to calculate results. Excessive info may be included to test students if they know what they are doing.